# Hibernate Session not bound to thread with AOP point cut transaction manager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I am using Spring 4.0.3 and Hibernate 3.6.10. I am experienced with Spring and Hibernate, but starting a new project from scratch.

Googled for my error and found about half a dozen and I don't think any of them help.

Here are the relevant definitions from my spring configuration file:

```
<!-- the transactional advice (what happens; see the <aop:advisor/> bean below) -->
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">
    <!-- the transactional semantics... -->
    <tx:attributes>
        <!-- all methods starting with get are read-only -->
        <tx:method name="get*" propagation="REQUIRED" read-only="true"/>
        <!-- other methods use the default transaction settings (see below) -->
        <tx:method name="" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>

<!-- ensure that the above transactional advice runs for any execution
    of an operation defined by the FooService interface -->
<aop:config>
    <aop:pointcut id="loaderOperation" expression="execution(* com.corrisoft.air.testload.loader.*.load(..))"/>
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="loaderOperation"/>
</aop:config>

<!-- similarly, don't forget the PlatformTransactionManager -->
<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="airDatabase"/>
</bean>

<util:list id="loaders" value-type="com.corrisoft.air.testload.loader.Loader">
    <ref bean="versionLoader"/>
</util:list>

<bean id="versionLoader" class="com.corrisoft.air.testload.loader.DeviceSoftwareLoader" init-method="init">
    <property name="versionDAO" ref="versionDAO"/>
</bean>
```

and here is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:65)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:687)
    com.corrisoft.air.data.hibernate.HibernateDAO.getCurrentSession(HibernateDAO.java:42)
    com.corrisoft.air.data.hibernate.HibernateDAO.create(HibernateDAO.java:62)
    **com.corrisoft.air.testload.loader.DeviceSoftwareLoader.load(DeviceSoftwareLoader.java:63)**
    com.corrisoft.air.testload.loader.DeviceSoftwareLoader$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1d5a010d.invoke(<generated>)
    org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    com.corrisoft.air.testload.loader.DeviceSoftwareLoader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$39a06195.load(<generated>)
    com.corrisoft.air.testload.LoadAir.load(LoadAir.java:37)
    com.corrisoft.air.web.ReloadController.handleRequestInternal(ReloadController.java:25)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:154)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

I'm confused, because the bolded line is the one that I wish to have the transaction wrap. When I look at the stack trace, it appears to me that it has started a transaction for me. So, why, then, am I getting the error?

Here's my hibernate and DAO setup:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="airDatabase" jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/airDB"/>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="airDatabase" />
    <property name="packagesToScan">
        <list>
            <value>com.corrisoft.air.model</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <value>
            hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
            hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="versionDAO" class="com.corrisoft.air.data.hibernate.DeviceSoftwareVersionHibernateDAO" init-method="init">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Is this a typo `tx:method name=""`?

Comment: I copied that from an example I found. I believe it means all other methods.

Comment: Try like this: `<tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>`

Comment: @AndreiStefan That appears to have done it. Thanks. Please post as an answer so I can tag it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your configuration: change the "other methods" tx matching to the following:

```
<tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED"/>
```